How enforce Proguard to obfuscate class names
I have classes, for sample:
public class AdvisorReport2 {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String additional;
}

After proguard obfuscation next mapping file generated:
com.package.AdvisorReport2 -> com.package.AdvisorReport2:
# {"id":"sourceFile","fileName":"AdvisorReport2.java"}

So, I see no any obfuscation of this class name and member/fields of class.
I'm expected to see something like this:
com.package.AdvisorReport2 -> com.package.AA:
# {"id":"sourceFile","fileName":"AdvisorReport2.java"}
    int id -> a
    String name -> b
    String additianal -> c

How can I obfuscate all classes names and all members of all classes of my package by default (except classes disable by -keep settings)?
